# javascript array of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have to iterate an array of checkboxes asking if the checkbox is checked but I couldn't get the results. Here is my code

```
var checkboxes = $(".checked"); 
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var check = checkboxes[i];
    if(check.prop('checked')){
        console.log("Checkbox number: " + i + " is checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: use `if($(check).prop('checked')){` instead of `if(check.prop('checked')){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `checkboxes[i]` in the loop it returns DOM elements instead of jQuery elements.

You can wrap `checkboxes[i]` with `$()` to make the DOM element a jQuery element:

```
var checkboxes = $(".checked"); 
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var check = $(checkboxes[i]);
    if(check.is(':checked')){
        console.log("Checkbox number: " + i + " is checked");
    }
}
```

I also changed `.prop('checked')` to `.is(':checked')`. It depends which version of jQuery you're using `prop` might be fine (>1.6). Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way can do,

```
var i = 0;
$(".checked").each(function(){
    if (this.checked){
        console.log("Checkbox number: " + i + " is checked");
        i++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.checked').each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log("Checkbox number: " + index + " is checked");
    }
});
```